# Coming back from a push view without a UINavigationController and a back button, is it possible?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a `ViewController`, for example `startingScreenViewController`. I have a push segue from an item on this view to another view (`someViewController`) which is a `ViewController` that has a `TableView` (not `TableViewController` of course) in it. Now, without having a back button I want to go back to the first view by tapping on a cell in table view. I have written my cell delegate:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
}
```

I tried using

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and obviously it didn't work, since I don't have a `navigationController`. I even tried to segue back to the `startingScreenViewController` which was a stupid thing to do and also didn't work.

I'm in need of some help, and suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've checked on test project, if you try to perform push segue without `UINavigationController` your app will crash with error: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of `UINavigationController`.'. So either you have `UINavigationController` or it's not push segue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you manage to open `someViewController` with push segue without `UINavigationController`, but if it works, try to use this code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And, of course, check, is your `view controller` `delegate` of `table view`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I also have done that. Nothing happens. The cell gets highlighted (in simulator) and you can still scroll up and down the table view. :(

Comment: Did you check that you are `delegate` of `UITableView`?

Comment: Yes I have done that too. Actually right now I tried pushing a cell several times, after pushing 4 times, It worked!! and I also tried popping back to the root view, It took me to my app's first page. is there a way i can the stack of NavigationController and i dont know maybe pop to the second one?

Comment: If `dismissViewControllerAnimated:` works, you don't have a navigation controller, it's modal segue I guess

Comment: Actually you are current, i dont have a UINavigation controller, but i was able to get the Array of views loaded in Navigation Controller and then pop to my desired view. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to not use a push segue when you don't have a navigation controller. That should not work at all, and the fact that it does work is an accident. There is no guarantee that it will continue to work in the future.

Use a modal presentViewController:animated:completion call, the dismiss it using the corresponding call.